# Google Play Store application always shows update - even after updating

Tags: android, google-play

I have uploaded a new version of my App, every time I install it on any device it shows me: Downloading->Installing -> Update (The update button keep reappearing on the Play Store instead of the open button, I also added ads (AdMob banner)in this version, and they are not showing (I tested it with the google banner example id and it worked),

this is my app:
https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.vladcorp.antimosquito&hl=en

When I run this on the android studio it runs smoothly,
Any ideas on why is this happening or what I can do?
thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Please check your AdMob code is for publish app on play store,
because your example id worked fine so.

Comment: I copy pasted it from the AdMob console